# Network traffic throttling using tc/tbf - unexpected results

Tags: networking

In order to facilitiate some performance testing I am attempting to throttle the ip traffic on a particular machine - I want limit it to 1Mbit/sec.

I have a separate test machine where this command works just fine:

tc qdisc add dev eth0 root tbf rate 1mbit burst 5kb latency 70ms peakrate 1.001mbit minburst 1540

On the real box where I want to apply this, I get weirdness. The exact same command limits traffic to 6Kbit/sec. Any ideas why?

unanme -a shows

`Linux IPERF1 2.6.18-128.el5PAE #1 SMP Wed Dec 17 12:02:33 EST 2008 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`

We have a three different ways of monitoring the throughput: The actual application we are testing which reports the throughput we see. We also some Tivoli monitoring on a switch and we have an HTTP client which downloads a file from an HTTP server on the box in question. All three methods show 6Kbs when the TBF is applied, and many Mbs when we remove the TBF.

Answer (score 2):

Timer resolution might influence your results, see [here](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.qdisc.classless.html#AEN691) for example. What happens if you increase burst to 10kb and remove peakrate and minburst?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't go back and check this. I'm pretty sure your idea is correct.